# mongolite doesn't read the index and read queries are slow

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, robo3t, mongolite

I have created a mongodb database using mongolite and I create index on the `_row` key on the database using following command:

```
collection$index(add = '{"_row" : 1}')
```

when I query a document via Robo3T program with the `db.getCollection('collection').find({"_row": "ENSG00000197616"})` command, my index works and it takes less than a second to query the data.

[Robo3T screen shot >>> pay attention to the query time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WB6L7.png)

This is also the case when I query the data using pymongo package in python.

[python screenshot >>> pay attention to query time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqNOh.png)

Surprisingly, when I perform the same query with mongolite, it takes more than 10 seconds to query data:

```
system.time(collection$find(query = '{"_row": "ENSG00000197616"}'))
```

user system elapsed

12.221 0.005 12.269

I think this can only come from mongolite package, otherwise, it wouldn't work on the other programs as well.

Any input is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:

https://github.com/jeroen/mongolite/issues/37

The time consuming part is not data query but simplifying it in a dataframe.